# How do I log a MixPanel event when a user clicks a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mixpanel

I'm trying to log an event in MixPanel when users click a certain type of link. I'm using JQuery to do it unobtrusively and as far as I understand I need to add a callback function to take the user to URL after the event has been logged.

This is the code I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#more-posts").click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
            mpq.track("More Posts", function(){
                window.location = $(this).attr("href");
            });
    });
</script>
```

Unfortunately this neither takes the user to the page nor logs the event, but I see no errors in the Javascript console in Chrome.

Any ideas what the problem may be?

Update: Also tried this code based on suggestions in the comments:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function go_to_link(link) {
        window.location = link;
    } 
    $("#more-posts").on("click", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            mpq.track("More Posts");
            setTimeout("go_to_link($("#more-posts").attr("href"))", 2000);
    });

</script>
```

It now redirects to the correct link, but still doesn't log an event.

Comment: Where does `event` comes from? It should be an argument of the click callback.

Comment: I don't think so. It's there to prevent the default behaviour of the click event so that the following code has a chance to execute. If I make the change you suggest, clicking just takes a user to the URL without logging the event. It also gives an "uncaught reference error".

Comment: What are the errors in chrome?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? You should really use `.on('click', function(event) {...}`.

Comment: The problem might be a similar problem I've experienced with KissMetrics. Their JavaScript code simply doesn't have time to listen for the event. Try doing a `setTimeout` before the redirect and see if it logs the event correctly. If it does, then this is your issue, and you likely want to log the click event after they reach the new location.

Comment: @Suhail There are no errors in Chrome, that's the confusing part.

Comment: @cutwithflourish Did you try my suggestion in the comments?

Comment: Hi Josh, yes tried them and doesn't seem to have fixed it. I'll update the answer with the code I'm trying at the moment that works in that it now takes the user to the link, but still doesn't log an event.

Comment: I spoke to MixPanel support and they suggested that my approach was not a reliable one. Instead they recommend tracking the event on the target page.

Answer (score 11):

Mixpanel has recently added a method [mixpanel.track_links](https://mixpanel.com/docs/integration-libraries/javascript-full-api#track_links) that does the job.

Answer (score 3):

The third argument of the mpq.track function is a callback. This code gets executed once the tracking has completed, and would be a reliable way to send the user to the other page.

```
$("#more-posts").on("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        mpq.track("More Posts", null, function() {
            go_to_link($("#more-posts").attr("href"))
        });
});
```

Comment: Then there is a chance that the callback is never call and your website would be broken.

Comment: That is correct, the callback might not get executed. A way around that would be to use some promise and deferred code, if the callback never runs (might happen <1% of the time) you could fallback to running the timed method.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a candidate for MixPanel support: support@mixpanel.com. The bug does not lie with your jQuery code. Here's a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZWe8J/) that demonstrates the basic functionality.

As I mentioned, I've seen similar issues with a `_kmq.push` with Kissmetrics. Their JS simply might not have time to register the event. If you try a longer timeout, it might work, but **this is bad UX**.

Update here if/when you reach out to MixPanel.

Comment: Thanks Josh, I've sent an email to MixPanel support - hopefully they can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using setTimeout, consider using the callback param of [mpq.track](http://mixpanel.com/docs/integration-libraries/javascript#track).

Alternatively, track the page load at the location that the link would have gone to.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the function callback in mixpanel.track which fires after the event is successfully logged.

Code would look like this.

```
mixpanel.track("Great Success!", {}, function(){
  window.location.href = "www.whatever.com";
});
```