# How can I track with Mixpanel the event of a user following my Twitter account by clicking the Twitter Follow button?

Tags: javascript, twitter, dom-events, mixpanel

Please bear with me, I'm not a developer.

I'd like to track the event of a site visitor clicking on my Twitter Follow Button with `Mixpanel`. Hence I run the following `Mixpanel` event/name:

```
<script> function clickTwitterFollowB() {
    mixpanel.track("Twitter button");       
        }</script>
```

I use `onclick` to load the `Mixpanel` function when the Twitter button is clicked:

```
onclick="clickTwitterFollowB()"
```

And this is the Twitter Button code where I insert the above:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/myAccount" onclick="clickTwitterFollowB()" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-size="large">Follow @myAccount</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

When I do the above, the event is not tracked, but it does track it does work on links "a""/a" and "button""/button".

Any ideas/suggestions on what might be wrong with this event tracking code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clinking the link loads another page, at which point the JS on your page is no longer relevant.

You have a couple options: [How do I log a MixPanel event when a user clicks a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657118/how-do-i-log-a-mixpanel-event-when-a-user-clicks-a-link)